# Turn single digit code into full word code python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a word encryption for my school and couldn't figure out how to turn it from single digit encryption into a full word. I want to be able to do full words not one letter at a time. I would be extremely  grateful if anyone could help me out with this problem

```
while True:
print("Input letters you would like to encrypt")
IN= input()

if IN=="a":
    print("BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="A":
    print("BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="b":
    print("ACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="B":
    print("ACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="c":
    print("ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="C":
    print("ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")   
elif IN=="d":
    print("ABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="D":
    print("ABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="e":
    print("ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="E":
    print("ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="f":
    print("ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="F":
    print("ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="g":
    print("ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="G":
    print("ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="h":
    print("ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="H":
    print("ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="i":
    print("ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="I":
    print("ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")       
elif IN=="j":
    print("ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="J":
    print("ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="k":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="K":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="l":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="L":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")        
elif IN=="m":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="M":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="n":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="N":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="o":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="O":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="p":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="P":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="q":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="Q":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ")        
elif IN=="r":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="R":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="s":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="S":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="t":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="T":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ")
elif IN=="u":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ")
elif IN=="U":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ")
elif IN=="v":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ")
elif IN=="V":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ")       
elif IN=="w":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ")
elif IN=="W":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ")
elif IN=="x":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ")
elif IN=="X":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ")
elif IN=="y":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ")
elif IN=="Y":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ")
elif IN=="z":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY")
elif IN=="Z":
    print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY")
else:
    print("One number at a time bud")
```

pass

Comment: I don't see the encryption algorithm and I don't know what you mean by a "full word code," and it looks like all you have here is a basic `if` structure. We won't finish your homework for you.

Comment: I'll finish your homework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you probably worked hard on your project but sadly I think that it might be a bit too minimalistic to be able to generate encrypted text.
What your code is currently doing is just, as you said, able to print 1 digit encryption.

Sadly, my knowledge with python has decreased but a simple google might be able to help you, which I had a quick look for so I hope this helps! 
http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/ 
This should hopefully help you out, it also provides you with a decrypter. if needs be,

**I got this from their documents,**

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import DES
>>> obj=DES.new('abcdefgh', DES.MODE_ECB)
>>> plain="Guido van Rossum is a space alien."
>>> len(plain)
34
>>> obj.encrypt(plain)
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ValueError: Strings for DES must be a multiple of 8 in length
>>> ciph=obj.encrypt(plain+'XXXXXX')
>>> ciph
'\021,\343Nq\214DY\337T\342pA\372\255\311s\210\363,\300j\330\250\312\347\342I\3215w\03561\303dgb/\006'
>>> obj.decrypt(ciph)
'Guido van Rossum is a space alien.XXXXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

while True:
  print("Input letters you would like to encrypt")
  IN= input().upper()

  if IN.upper() in ascii_uppercase:
    print(ascii_uppercase.replace(IN, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to return the *complement* of the roman alphabet with respect to the letters provided.

There are a few ways to do this:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
def reduce_complement_alpha(letters):
    res = reduce(lambda letter: alphabet.replace(letter, ''), letters.upper(), ascii_uppercase)
    return res

def set_complement_letters(letters):
    res = ''.join(sorted(set(ascii_upper) - set(letters.upper())))
    return res

def filter_complement_letters(letters):
    res = ''.join(filter(lambda l: l not in letters.upper(), ascii_uppercase))
    return res
```

Those are just a few examples :) The first feature O(n log n) time complexity but in practice since your n is very small it doesn't matter, while the last one has a linear O(n) time complexity.